# send confirmation mail using sendgrid through django

Tags: python, postgresql, django-models

view.py
class Signup(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'sign_up.html'

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    Form = Sign_up()
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': Form})

def post(self, request):
    data = self.request.POST.get
    try:
        user = User(
            first_name=data('first_name'),
            last_name=data('last_name'),
            email=data('email'),
            username=data('username'),
        )
        user.set_password(data('password').strip())
        user.is_active = False
        user.save()
        request.session['SESSION_KEY'] = user.id

        try:
            sg = SendGridAPIClient(api_key=settings.SENDGRID_API_KEY)
            from_email = "commerce@gmail.com"
            to_email = "usmanimtiaz9991@gmail.com"
            subject = "Sending with SendGrid is Fun"
            content = Content("text/plain", "and easy to do anywhere, even with Python")
            mail = Mail(from_email, subject, to_email, content)
            response = sg.client.mail.send.post(request_body=mail.get())
            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, response.status_code, response.body, response.headers)
            return HttpResponse('done')
        except Exception as c:
            return HttpResponse('failed:{}'.format(c), 500)
    except Exception as e:
        return HttpResponse('failed {}'.format(e), 500)
```

class ActivateAccount(View):

```
def get(self, request, uidb64, token, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except (TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        user = None

    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.profile.email_confirmed = True
        user.save()
        login(request, user)
        messages.success(request, 'Your account have been confirmed.')
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        messages.warning(request, 'The confirmation link was invalid, possibly because it has already been used.')
        return redirect('home')
```

Models.py

from django.db import models

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from django.db.models.signals import post_save

from django.dispatch import receiver

class Profile(models.Model):

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

email_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)

def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):

```
if created:

    Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

    instance.profile.save()
```

settings.py

EMAIL_BACKEND = "sgbackend.SendGridBackend"

SENDGRID_API_KEY = 'apikey'

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'

EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'apikey'

EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = SENDGRID_API_KEY

EMAIL_PORT = 587

EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

My Signup function work correctly it show error HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

Comment: What is the error message? Can you share it?

Comment: after sign up values save in db but it show this error HTTP Error 400: Bad Request during sending mail

Comment: Your method work correctly but email send process give Bad Request response, right?

Comment: I look at the send grid document and realized a point. Could you change to and from parts like that:
 from_email = Email("test@example.com")
to_email = To("test@example.com")
 Please use Email and To functions and try again.

Comment: Now i get this error: Object of type To is not JSON serializable

Comment: i almost try every method even i set my sendgrid api key as environment variable and also connect sendgrid to my system through cmd, but still errors

Comment: I think your Mail method parameters order is wrong please change with Mail(from_email, to_email, subject, content) (to_email and subject orders wrong)

Comment: now that error occur: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Comment: Ok,I think your request is correct now. Perhaps your account credentials can be wrong or like that from_email or your account plan has restrict.